# WCF: parameter not coming through as null

Tags: wcf, soap, soapui

I have a wcf service having the following operation:

```
public NewPCNResponse CreateNewPcnExtended(NewPcnExtendedData newPcnExtendedData, string chargeBand, string deviceId, decimal? usageCharge, string plateType)
```

Note the camel cased parameter chargeBand. The problem is with all the camel cased parameters but I am taking this one for demonstration.

I am using SoapUi to test the calls and the following is the relevant part of the SOAP request:

[image]

The element is camel cased and even though it is nullable, it comes thorough as an empty string as shown in the following screenshot:
[image]

this fails the validation which I have down the line. 
However if the argument is pascal cased, it comes through fine

[image]

[image]

The easier solution for me to change the casing but I want to know the reason behind this odd behaviour and if I want to keep the argument camel cased what option do I have.

Comment: Maybe, you are sending empty string instead of null with SoapUI. Delete chargeBand line in SoapUI.

Comment: The part of the request is shown above and surely an empty string is not what I am sending and hence it comes through as null when I change the casing. Deleting it is another option but only with SoapUI and not in production and even then it doesn't explain the behaviour.

Comment: If you are using DataContracts you can add this attribute to that public property so that it will not emit its default value: `[DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]`

Comment: Is the XML valid (according to the schema) in both cases?

Comment: There is no change to schema in either cases except for changing 'c' to 'C' so I reckon the xml is correct.

Comment: I'm quite certain that the schema is case sensitive. ChargeBand and chargeBand are NOT the same entities. (At least not in SoapUI) And only one of them is schema valid, unless you also change the schema. My guess is that the one that is correctly being interpreted as NULL is the one that validates.

Comment: there is no denying the schema is case sensitive and nobody is questioning that. Did the code images load properly?